# Access the feeds of a facebook business page?

Tags: facebook

How I can access the feeds of a Facebook business page? I am not allowed to create apps, so I wont get an app access token? But i need a access token to retrieve data?

So how can I get a non expiring access token?

**EDIT:**

I try the following to get a token, but session is always NULL:

```
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('ID','SECRET');

$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('http://www.mydomain.de/facebook/test.php');
$session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get an access token without using an application. You can try using `https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=rss20&id=PAGE_ID` as an alternative but this might be deprecated in the future.

e.g. https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=rss20&id=20531316728

Comment: So I have to create an app on my users account and link me to the business page as a admin to get access?

Comment: @nofear87 no. Any access token can be used to view public posts, you don't need to be an admin of the page https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/page/feed

Comment: ahh ok, thank you! And can I get a token without entering my personal credentials? Only with app id and secret?

Comment: @nofear87 no. The only token that doesn't require login is the application token and you should not be using this for any use other than administration. Please take a moment to read the documentation https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/v2.2

Comment: that means I can't share my facebook feeds on a webpage to users which havent a facebook profile (because they are not able to get an access token)

Comment: @nofear87 as long as you extend a user token you should be able to get a page token with no expiry that you can save in your database.  Read https://developers.facebook.com/docs/roadmap/completed-changes/offline-access-removal#extend_token

Comment: ok, that means I should make a request every 2 hours (expiration time) to extend the token? Or How long the long life token is valid?

Comment: @nofear87 no as long as you extend it, I already gave you the documentation on how to do that

Comment: we are talking about scenario 4? But there is written: "..endpoint can only be used to extend the short-lived user access_tokens.." but I dont know how long this extensions will be?

Comment: @nofear87 scenario 5.

Comment: I updated my start post! I try to get the first token via the php sdk. But the session is always NULL.I am not sure if I use the correct redirect domain...must it be the same as I set in the app settings?

Comment: whats the best way to get th page access token with the sdk? is there a good tutorial?